# Creating multiple records fails in odoo13 yet passes in odoo12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I have this function that allocates multiple bonuses to employee contracts.

My particular problem is that when I call this function, it throws the error, `Expected singleton failed to unpack multiple records ...`

The `contract_ids` am using is a many2many field with relation to the model hr.contract.

I understand the cause of a singleton error but am using a for loop for every create call so I do not know where my error is.

```
  def action_allocate_bonus(self):
        for rec in self.contract_ids:
            vals = {
                'contract_id': rec.id,
                'cash_allowance_id': self.cash_allowance_id.id,
                'computation': 'fixed',
                'fixed': rec.allowance_amount,
            }
            self.env['ke.cash_allowances'].sudo().create(vals)
```

This is the actual log error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5000, in ensure_one
    _id, = self._ids
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1326, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/api.py", line 388, in call_kw
    model.flush()
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5389, in flush
    self.recompute()
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5808, in recompute
    process(field)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5792, in process
    recs.mapped(field.name)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5206, in mapped
    recs = recs._mapped_func(operator.itemgetter(name))
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5165, in _mapped_func
    vals = [func(rec) for rec in self]
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5165, in <listcomp>
    vals = [func(rec) for rec in self]
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5616, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/fields.py", line 997, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/fields.py", line 1111, in compute_value
    records._compute_field_value(self)
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 3915, in _compute_field_value
    getattr(self, field.compute)()
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/custom-addons/hr_ke/models/payroll.py", line 485, in compute_cash_allowance
    if self.computation == 'fixed':
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/fields.py", line 984, in __get__
    record.ensure_one()
  File "/home/b14/odoo-dev/odoo13/odoo/models.py", line 5003, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: ke.cash_allowances(33, 34)
```

The code being referenced in the payroll models is this

```
@api.depends('computation', 'fixed')
def compute_deduction(self):
    if self.computation == 'fixed':
        self.amount = self.fixed

    elif self.computation == 'formula':
        baselocaldict = {
            'result': None,
            'employee': self.employee_id,
            'deduction': self}
        localdict = dict(baselocaldict)
        try:
            Eval(self.formula, localdict, mode='exec', nocopy=True)
        except BaseException:
            raise ValidationError(
                    _('Error in the formula defined for this\
                      deduction: %s\n [%s].') %
                    (self.name, self.formula))
        self.amount = localdict['result']
    else:
        self.amount = 0.00
```

Comment: If you're using odoo12 please add @api.multi decorator on method

Comment: @AdamStrauss, I am using odoo13

Comment: Please update your question with the log error

Comment: Yes @Kenly is saying right thing....

Comment: I have updated, Thank you

Comment: But this is in a for loop, all the variables should change in every iteration, some variables can be shared like fields that are selection

Comment: The problem is in `compute_cash_allowance` when you try to get the value of `computation ` in `if self.computation == 'fixed':`. You need to loop over `self` to get the field value. You can check the [Computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) documentation

Comment: Did you fix that error?

Comment: Thank you at @Kenly, I have just settled down and tried your suggestion and it works fine. A few more issues but fixed them by looping over them.

Comment: Thank you @AdamStrauss

Comment: I am glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's "self" that's causing the error, being a set of multiple records but being referred to as being a single record.
More specifically in the first line of `compute_deduction` it already hits an issue where it doesn't know what the `computation` field should return for 2 different fields.
I think you might want to put the entire method in a for loop and then use the record instead of self.
like this:

```py
@api.depends('computation', 'fixed')
def compute_deduction(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.computation == 'fixed':
            record.amount = record.fixed
        ....
```